# post request to Rest Api with c# and httpclient

Tags: c#, python, rest, windows-phone, httpclient

There is such code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username:", " 1"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password:", " 1"));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    "http://libdiary.liberty-lab.ru/api/v1/login", 
    content);

string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return result;
```

He must make a post request to the server. The project is windows phone. 
Feature on the server that is responsible for this query looks like (Python):

```
def log_in(request):
    username = request.META['HTTP_USERNAME']
    password = request.META['HTTP_PASSWORD']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        content = json.dumps('Your welcome dear user!')
        return HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        content = json.dumps('Sorry! Please, check your name or password.')
        return HttpResponse(content, content_type='application/json')
```

However, attempts to access a windows phone always an `error:INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` and in the application code returned http page with an [error on this page](http://libdiary.liberty-lab.ru/api/v1/login). Could you tell what the problem is? Perhaps I am wrong to send data, can you suggest how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the `request` object on keys named `HTTP_USERNAME` and `HTTP_USERNAME` which don't exist. Either change them at the call site or at the target site:

```
username = request.META['username']
password = request.META['password']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I had the same problem. Same mistake error:INTERNAL SERVER ERROR,  but the site itself is now written with an error instead of "HTTP_USERNAME" on it "username".

Comment: @Egor Do you have the exception message and stacktrace?

Comment: KeyError at /api/v1/login
'username'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://libdiary.liberty-lab.ru/api/v1/login
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'username'

Line:
username = request.META['username']

Comment: @EgorSimakhin Are you sure your request parameters are placed inside `request.META`? can you debug the code?

Comment: I think yes, but not sure. The original function works with the extension for Google Chrome, which is called Advanced Rest Client. That is, the request is sent, and there comes the answer, the user logged on. But when I send the request through a telephone application, there's this error.

Comment: It might be in the way the data is serialized. You have to debug your code to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The server checks the username and password that were in Headers. I just added a new header "username" and new header "password" and assign them appropriate values.

```
  HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
        content.Headers.Add("username", "1");
        content.Headers.Add("password", "2");
```

Thanks for the help, especially Yuval Itzchakov.